# How to get an root cause of an Exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, uwp

I am getting an error in an UWP APP? So I am debugging it to find a root cause.

```
 private async Task<byte[]> getResponse(string[] pathSegments, string json)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _communicator.Post(pathSegments, json);
                //Tools.Logger.Debug(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) ? "OJMAR API returned empty result." : "OJMAR API returned: " + response);

                var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoD.Devices.Lockers.Ojmar.Shared.DO.Responses.CardDataResponse>(response);
```

from
`var response = await _communicator.Post(pathSegments, json);`

it jumps to Task

```
public async Task<string> Post(string[] pathSegments, string json)
        {
            var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return await _apiAddress
                .AppendPathSegments(pathSegments)
                .PostJsonAsync(obj)
                .ReceiveString();    
        }
```

but after that it directly jump into exception which is

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
```

It just throws a message **An error sending a request** but I am not getting that how can I trace a root cause for it that's where I am stuck because it could be several reasons not able to send a request.

Comment: Anything in `ex.InnerException`?

Comment: I doubt that's literally the exception message, anyway, just write `ex`, not only its message. Or better, set a breakpoint and inspect it.

Comment: @KlausGütter It is showing null. But in exception in shows                                        ** Exception{Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Request http://192.168.2.234:8086/serialization/userCard failed. An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found. **

Comment: You could try to use another Url to test your project to check if the exception is related with the certain Url.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Visual Studio debugging for this.

In the first instance let the exception happen and break in the exception handler to determine the exact exception that's being raised.

Once you know this, restart the debugging session and just before you initiate the action that raises the exception go to the "Exception Settings" tab and search for that exception. Tick the option to "Break When Thrown" and then continue the execution.

[image: The Exception Settings pane with the search box and exception highlighted]

Visual Studio will then break at the nearest code line it has to the actual exception. So if the exception is being raised in the .NET framework or some 3rd party code you might not be able to see the exact line, but you will see which line of your code is making the call.